# Relationship between Cardinality of Kleene Closure and Powerset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By Cantor's Theorem, we know that $|\mathcal{P}(S)| > |S|$

Given a finite set $A$. We can see that $|A^*| \ge |\mathcal{P}(A)|$ since the cardinality of the powerset is $2^{|A|}$ and the cardinality of the Kleene closure is some type of infinity (e.g. $\{\epsilon, a, aa, aaa, ...\}$ where $A := \{a\}$)

Can we somehow show that for any (finite or infinite) set $A$, $|A^*| \ge |\mathcal{P}(A)|$?

If $A$ is infinite, will $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = |A^*| = \aleph_0$?

*Note:* I say $\ge$ not $>$ because of the case $A := \emptyset$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A \neq \emptyset$, whether A is finite or infinite, the cardinality of $A^*$ is:

$$\begin{align}
|A^*| &= |A|^{<\omega} \\
&= \max(\omega, |A|) \\
\end{align}
$$

which is just $|A|$ when $A$ is infinite. So for infinite A it's *always* the case that $|\mathcal{P}(A)| > |A^*|$.

For a cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa^{<\omega}$ is defined as:
$$
\kappa^{<\omega} \triangleq \Sigma_{n < \omega} \kappa^n
$$
Just fyi, $\kappa^{<\lambda}$ has an analogous definition, but no need to over-generalize here.

Note that $A^* = \bigcup_{n<\omega} A^n$, where $A^n$ is the set of length $n$ sequences of elements of $A$ (equivalently, $n$-tuples of elements of $A$). The $A^n$ are pairwise disjoint ($A \neq \emptyset$), so the cardinality of the Kleene closure of $A$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
|A^*| &= \lvert \bigcup_{n<\omega} A^n \rvert \\
&= \Sigma_{n<\omega}|A^n| \\
&= \Sigma_{n<\omega}|A|^n \\
&= |A|^{<\omega}
\end{align}
$$

Computing $\kappa^{<\omega}$ is simple. For infinite $\kappa$, 
$$
\begin{align}
\kappa &\le \kappa^{<\omega} \\
&= \Sigma_{n < \omega} \kappa^n \\
&= \Sigma_{n < \omega} \kappa \\
&= \omega \times \kappa \\
&= \max(\omega, \kappa) \\
&= \kappa \\
\end{align}
$$

For finite $\kappa$, clearly $\kappa^{<\omega} = \omega$.

The cardinal arithmetic above assumes the Axiom of Choice (AC). As Noah Schweber points out in his comment, in the absence of AC, it's consistent for there to be an $A$ such that $A^*$ is "larger than" $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: Technical side note: this fails without the axiom of choice. If $A$ is *amorphous*, then $A^*$ is strictly larger than $\mathcal{P}(A)$, in the sense that there is a surjection from $A^*$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$ but not conversely.

Comment: @Noah Schweber Thanks for the insight. And people say that AC has paradoxical consequences ;)

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for the response. Can you elaborate on $<\omega$ and why that's the cardinality of $A^*$? I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Sure, I wondered if I was being too terse with that notation. I'll flesh that out.